# Mistake done by MSE in calculating score.

Tags: discussion, support, bug

In my profile of Mathematics SE, it shows that I've score of $7$ in `algebra-precalculus` tag.

[image]

However, if you manually count the scores of all the questions answered by of these tag, it comes out to be $9$. You can check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:782505+%5Balgebra-precalculus%5D).

Is these really a mistake by the system or it will take time to appear the correct number?

**(This question is solved now, no need to worry. )**

Comment: Your latest answer, which happens to have score 2,  is very recent. Not everything is updated in (near) real-time. I'd wait a bit, say a day. Differently, yes, I think it just will take time for the correct number to appear.

Comment: @quid you're right but this is a recent problem. This happened just three or four days ago...some reputaiton points aren't added after 24h...I have never seen this bfore.

Comment: @Aryadeva if this is the case then please report it as such.

Comment: I will. Note that the reputation points are added after some days. They're not lost. In the past at a certain time  the reputaion points were updated. Always at the same hour. @quid

Comment: @Aryadeva interesting. I did not know that. It seems possible that this is even an intentional change.

Comment: Yes I think so too. @quid.

Comment: If you'd like we can delete some of your answers to make it correct again! `:-)`

Comment: I note that you [edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3738737/2) one of the questions to include the tag.  [Your answer to that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3738757/468350) has received two upvotes, which accounts for the discrepancy.

Comment: ...or maybe not.  After perusing the rest of the SE network, I don't see anything which backs up my theory.

Comment: The link you give finds seven search results with the tag, but your "top tags" for that category reflects only six posts.  Perhaps the retagging will be caught in  a recalculation.

Comment: Just to check the count, here is link to [search for non-CW answers by this user in the algebra-precalculus tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A782505+%5Balgebra-precalculus%5D+wiki%3A0).

Comment: Your profile page has now updated to show a score of $9$ and that $7$ posts are counted.

Comment: @hardmath, yes. Now, I got that the changes take time to appear rather than making it up instantly. :-)